# boost::property_tree, My program crashes when I write something to the configuration file. C++

Tags: c++, boost, crash

*sorry my bad english launguage*

Hi guys, i looking a help because i have problem with library in c++ boost.org
I have configuration file: Example

```
Checkbox Number:[0]=0
Checkbox Number:[1]=0
Checkbox Number:[2]=2
Checkbox Number:[3]=2
```

And when I write something for this file: Exapmle

```
Checkbox Number:[0]=0
Checkbox Number:[1]=0
Checkbox Number:[2]=2
Checkbox Number:[3]=2
NewChecbox Number:[4]=2
```

And that causes my program to crash.

My code to read cfg file:

```
SDK::F->CreateDir("CFG");//Create new directory
boost::property_tree::ptree py; 
QCheckBox* checkbox[]//Qt checkboxes
    = { SDK::gui->checkBox,
SDK::gui->checkBox_2,
SDK::gui->checkBox_3,
SDK::gui->checkBox_4
};
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(checkbox); i++)
{
    static char checckbox[1000];
    sprintf(checckbox, "Checkbox Number:[%d]",i);
    py.put(checckbox, checkbox[i]->checkState());
}

boost::property_tree::write_ini("CFG/ConfigLauncher.cfg", py);
```

What do I need to change in order for the program not to crash

Comment: You may replace `py.put(checckbox, checkbox[i]->checkState());` with `py.put(checckbox, 1);` and `for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(checkbox); i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` to see that the problem isn't in property_tree code.

Comment: It would save a lot of time for others if you make your core [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: this isnt fix for my problem bro

Comment: bro? Anyways, what you show is writing code, and [it just works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9422b7a8d105a7a1). Your question says  it's a problem when _reading_. You need to show that part of the code.